# Autorun на флешке

Tags: windows, usb

Авторан работает на старых версиях windows, на 7 и 10 уже не работает из-за безопасности. Есть ли способ все же запустить этот авторан при подключении флешки к пк?

Comment: И хорошо, что не работает. А Вам для того, что бы Ваша флешка везде запускалась или только на своем компе?

Comment: везде. ну и для своего тоже, чтобы проверить работает или нет

Comment: Авторан - не существует. Существует локальное программное обеспечение, выполняющее эту функцию. Если на некоей рабстанции оно отключено, не настроено на запуск или вообще отсутствует - вот на пупе извернись, а никакого авторана тебе не будет в принципе, потому как и быть не может - ибо, как сказано выше, авторан не существует.

Comment: ну смотри, есть диски которые автоматически открывают загрузчик программы к примеру, после того как вставишь в дисковод